# Сортировка по элементу коллекции

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net, linq, сортировка

Есть две таблицы `Images` и `Tags` (многие ко многим). Объединены они с помощью вспомогательной таблицы `Image_tag`.
Также играет роль очередность тегов, поэтому в таблицу `Image_tag`, помимо двух внешних ключей, добавлено поле `index`.
Делаю поиск `context.Images.Where(x => x.Image_tag.Any(a => a.Tag.Name == "tag"))`.
Можно ли как-то полученную коллекцию отсортировать по полю `Index` таблицы `Image_tag`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
from x in context.Images
let tag = x.Image_tag.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Tag.Name == "tag")
where tag != null
order by tag.Tag.Index
select x
```

Answer (score 1):

Если у вас поле `Index` типа `int` (или любого другого, поддерживающего упорядочивание), используйте [List.Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b0zbh7b6(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var list = context.Images.Where(x => x.Image_tag.Any(a => a.Tag.Name == "tag")).ToList();
list.Sort((x, y) => x.Index.CompareTo(y.Index));
```

Если нет - имплементируйте для этого типа интерфейс [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Макс Жуков, а почему сразу не воспользоваться `OrderBy(x => ...)`?